# how to negate a bitmap in android?

Tags: android, image

I want to display the negative of a dicom image , by using bitmap I did so

```
public static Bitmap getNegativeImage(Bitmap img) {
            int w1 = img.getWidth();
            int h1 = img.getHeight();
            // int value[][] = new int[w1][h1];
            Bitmap gray = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    w1, h1, img.getConfig());
            int value, alpha, r, g, b;
            for (int i = 0; i < w1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < h1; j++) {
                    value = img.getPixel(i, j); // store value

                    alpha = getAlpha(value);
                    r = 255 - getRed(value);
                    g = 255 - getGreen(value);
                    b = 255 - getBlue(value);

                    value = createRGB(alpha, r, g, b);
                    gray.setPixel(i, j, value);
                }
            }
            return gray;
        }

        public static int createRGB(int alpha, int r, int g, int b) {
            int rgb = (alpha << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
            return rgb;
        }

        public static int getAlpha(int rgb) {
            return (rgb >> 24) & 0xFF;
        }

        public static int getRed(int rgb) {
            return (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        }

        public static int getGreen(int rgb) {
            return (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        }

        public static int getBlue(int rgb) {
            return rgb & 0xFF;
        }
```

But the inverted(negative ) image gets black out, on clicking again the original image appears but the inverted image is not displayed.

Regards
Sathya U M

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why your code won't work, but this should:

```
private static final int RGB_MASK = 0x00FFFFFF;

public Bitmap invert(Bitmap original) {
    // Create mutable Bitmap to invert, argument true makes it mutable
    Bitmap inversion = original.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    // Get info about Bitmap
    int width = inversion.getWidth();
    int height = inversion.getHeight();
    int pixels = width * height;

    // Get original pixels
    int[] pixel = new int[pixels];
    inversion.getPixels(pixel, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    // Modify pixels
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels; i++)
        pixel[i] ^= RGB_MASK;
    inversion.setPixels(pixel, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    // Return inverted Bitmap
    return inversion;
}
```

It creates a *mutable* copy of the Bitmap (not all Bitmaps are), inverts the rgb part of all pixels, leaving alpha intact

**Edit**
I have an idea of why your code isn't working: you're assuming that the pixels are AARRGGBB

Comment: i am assuming the pixels as ARGB_8888

Comment: It [works for me](http://www.mediafire.com/?7mm5q95joigxcos), which suggests something else in your implementation is wrong. Please provide more code. Edit: or maybe start a new thread instead